# SQL queries trouble asp.net web pages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-webpages

So I'm making a simple asp.net web pages application in webmatrix, but I'm stuck with SQL problems. I'm working on an assigment and we're using the microsoft asp.net web pages tutorial as guideline (http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started). But when trying to run a query to update the database it keeps failing.

The error I'm getting is the following:

> System.FormatException: 0
>   Line 26:         var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
>   Line 27:         var deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM Gift WHERE ID = @0";
>   Line 28:         db.Execute(deleteCommand, Id); <-- crashing right here
>   Line 29:         Response.Redirect("~/ShowDbTest");
>   Line 30:     }

It tells me the order of the arguments is wrong like it would be an overloading error.

But I can't figure out what is wrong, so if someone could tell me what mistake I'm making, that would be great.

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
var gift = "";
var likeability = "";
var Id = "";

if(!IsPost){
    if(!Request.QueryString["id"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["id"].IsInt()){
        Id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM Gift WHERE ID = @0";
        var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, Id);

        if(row != null) {
            gift = row.Gift;
            likeability = row.Likeability;
        }
        else{
            Validation.AddFormError("No Gift was selected.1");
        }
    }
    else{
        Validation.AddFormError("No Gift was selected.2");
    }
}

if(IsPost){
    Validation.RequireField("gift", "You must enter a gift");
    Validation.RequireField("likeability", "Genre is required");
    Validation.RequireField("id", "No ID was submitted!");

    gift = Request.Form["gift"];
    likeability = Request.Form["likeability"];
    Id = Request.Form["Id"];

    if(Validation.IsValid()){
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var updateCommand = "UPDATE Gift SET Gift=@0, Likeability=@1 WHERE ID=@2";
        db.Execute(updateCommand, gift, likeability, Id);
        Response.Redirect("~/showDbTest");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you check you get value every time in `Request.QueryString["id"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is case sensitive.

Try this : Id = Request.Form["**id**"];

Also use : if(!Request.QueryString["id"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["id"].IsInt())

Also, don't forget to close the connection. You are making a redirect and the connection will remain opened. Use USING

Comment: c# might be case sensitive, but the keys in a NameValueCollection are not unless explicitly specified as being case sensitive.

Comment: True. Let see what WJZ responds.

Comment: Thank you very much. The request form was kinda the problem but I wasn't using a value in my hidden html field(which you couldn't see because I didn't think you needed my html code). But thanks for the tip about closing the database because I totally forgot to close it.

Comment: @CristiRoman So this is kinda weird, the request.querystring was kind of the problem and this fixed it. But on a different page the almost exact same code crashes. The only difference is I'm editing instead of deleting but it fails again. I will update the code if you don't mind taking another look.

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring ID as string and the database is (hopefully) defined as integer, this may well be causing conversion issues.

Cast your 'Id' into the type that is defined within the database and pass this in.

```
var Id= Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```